# Difference in syntax for anchors with IDs

Tags: css, anchor

Is there a difference between

```
ul#mainNav li a:active {
    color: #0312a4;}
```

and

```
 ul#mainNav li.active a {
color: #0312a4;}
```

? From what I can tell, they do the same thing.

Comment: :active is a property in css where .active is a class which you are putting on li element

Comment: first one is used to style a closed link & other is a style class added to give more style to some other tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes difference is there

ul#mainNav li a:active {
    color: #0312a4;}

in this, `active` is a pseudo class. It will apply color to `a` when event happen like click and hold (Eg: link,visited,hover,active etc.. are pseudo classes and always starts with `:`)
and

ul#mainNav li.active a {
color: #0312a4;}

in this, `active` is a class.(color will apply to anchor tag when the parent element li tag with `active` class only.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are completely different. Do check below snippet that will show you difference. Click to first text so it will show green color to you.

`a:active` means when anchor tag is active and `li.active` a class "active" is set to li tag.

```css
ul#mainNav li.active a {
  color: red;
}

ul#mainNav li a:active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mainNav">
  <li><a>Click Here</a></li>    
  <li class="active"><a>Click Here</a></li>    
</ul>
```